# Prépositions usuelles unissant « (faire un) tour » et « montagnes russes » ?

Tags: expressions, usage, prépositions, mots-composés

Le mot [tour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour) est [employé](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4162) dans un grand nombre d'[expressions](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tour/78664/locution) et a plusieurs [sens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tour) incluant le « mouvement, le déplacement (à peu près) circulaire au cours duquel on revient à son point de départ » (TLFi), comme dans le *[tour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour/2) de [manège](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/man%C3%A8ge)*...

- Peut-on classer du plus usuel au moins usuel l'emploi des
  prépositions *dans, de, en, sur,* après le mot [*tour*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tour%20de%20*%2Ctour%20sur%20*%2Ctour%20en%20*%2Ctour%20dans%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ctour%20de%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20r%C3%B4le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20scrutin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20force%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20main%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20Babel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20bras%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20France%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20l%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ctour%20sur%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20lui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ctour%20en%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20bois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20ma%C3%A7onnerie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20trois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20faveur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20ruines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20France%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ctour%20dans%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20l%27%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20ses%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ctour%20de%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20de%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20r%C3%B4le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20l'%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20scrutin%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20force%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20main%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20Babel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20bras%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20France%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20de%20l%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ctour%20sur%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20l'%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20lui%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20sur%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ctour%20en%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20en%20deux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20l'%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20bois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20ma%C3%A7onnerie%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20trois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20faveur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20ruines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20en%20France%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ctour%20dans%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20la%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20le%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20les%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20l'%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20une%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20son%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20cette%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20des%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btour%20dans%20ses%3B%2Cc0) quand il s'agit de [*montagnes russes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/montagnes_russes) (*faire un tour* [préposition (+art./déter.)] *montagnes russes*) ?
- Y a-t-il des variations notables de cet ordre selon qu'on se trouve à un endroit ou à un autre de la francophonie ?
- Sans l'emploi du mot *tour* est-on familier avec la formulation «
   veux-tu aller dans/sur les montagnes russes ? » (quand on se trouve déjà dans un [*parc d'attractions*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17017852) par exemple) ?

Comment: Pour ajouter à la donne même si c'est peu significatif en soi, j'ai trouvé dans un moteur de recherche près de 20 000 résultats avec _dans_; 45 000 avec _de_ ; 8400 avec _en_  et 25 000 avec _sur_ pour une requête sur l'expression exacte « _tour_ [préposition] _montagnes russes_ ». _Aller sur_ 26 000, _dans_ 8300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Une recherche de [*"montagnes russes"*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=15&page=1&query=%28gallica%20adj%20%22montagnes%20russes%22%29&filter=sdewey%20all%20%2284%22&lang=FR) sur Gallica nous donne de très nombreux résultats, dont plusieurs introduisant le sujet avec *tour*, mais aussi avec des équivalents comme *circuit* ou *parcours*. Au Québec, on entendra aussi régulièrement l’anglicisme *ride*, mais on le lira moins souvent, et il est vraisemblablement absent des publications.

Je n’ai pas joué le jeu de recenser et classer l’ensemble des occurrences, mais il m’a semblé que ***sur** les montagnes russes* l’emporte, mais suivi néanmoins de pas trop loin par ***dans** les montagnes russes*. Mon expérience personnelle du français canadien tend à percevoir une situation inverse au Québec, mais mon échantillon est biaisé vers certaines régions au détriment d’autres.

Le terme est très souvent repris figurativement pour imager une alternance quelconque de hauts et de bas (un sentier en montagnes russes, des montagnes russes d’émotions, etc.). Quelques-uns des exemples soumis dans la suite seront de cette nature.

> #### Avec *sur*
>
> ***Sur les montagnes russes*** telles qu’elles fonctionnent aujourd’hui à Paris, on ne court pas autant de danger que dans un train express, avec cette différence, tout à leur avantage, que le trajet n’a guère que 80 mètres et ne dure pas plus de 12 secondes.
> <sub>—Grand dictionnaire universel du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle / Pierre Larousse, 1866-1877</sub>
>
> Courbes très brusques, dénivellations très marquées des rails, tout fait de ce passage un point difficile, où le train ne s’engage qu’avec une sage lenteur ; malgré cela, ce sont des à-coups sans nombre, et notre wagon tangue ***comme sur de véritables montagnes... russes*** ; c’est d’ailleurs tout à fait l’aspect que présente cette partie de la voie regardée dans sa longueur.
> <sub>—À travers la Mandchourie : le chemin de fer de l’Est chinois / par Hippolyte-Marie-Joseph-Antoine Enselme (Capitaine), 1903</sub>
>
> Ils sont encore sur les manèges de chevaux de bois, ***sur les montagnes russes***, et surtout à l’Esplanade, sur le toboggan, dont la nouveauté les étonne.
> <sub>—Le Grand écho du Nord de la France (Lille), 1904</sub>
>
> J’aime à me rappeler mes courses dans ses rues larges et montueuses, dont les tramways descendent les pentes avec une rapidité qui vous fait perdre haleine, comme ***sur les montagnes russes***.
> <sub>—Voyage d’une Suissesse autour du monde / Cécile de Rodt, 1904</sub>
>
> Ainsi va l’exploration, en chutes et redressements, ***sur les montagnes russes de l’air***.
> <sub>—Les vagabonds de la gloire. 2<sup>e</sup> série, Trois étapes : l’armée d’Orient, l’aviation maritime, l’Italie / René Milan, 1917</sub>
>
> Berce-moi,
>         Vent de suroît,
> De tes violences aux rythmes longs.
> Roule-moi ***sur tes montagnes russes*** de sons
>         Qui courent,
> Montent, descendent, s’éloignent, se rapprochent
> Avec le bruit terrible et sourd
>         D’une avalanche de roches.
> <sub>—La Proue : revue des poëtes indépendants, 1932</sub>
>
> On se croirait ***sur des montagnes russes***, dit Mésange.
> <sub>—Planète verte. Le chalutier du désert / Gérard Streiff, 1998</sub>
>
> #### Avec *sur*, mais sans l’article défini
>
> Ce ne sera plus qu’une promenade amusante ***sur montagnes russes*** quand l’itinéraire à suivre aura été jalonné.
> <sub>—Revue mensuelle / Touring-club de France, 1919</sub>
>
> #### Avec *dans*
>
> Charmantes antithèses entre lesquelles le faible, esprit public, secoué plus violemment que ***dans les Montagnes russes***, finissait par ne plus savoir ni ce qu’il pensait, ni ce qu’il craignait, ni ce qu’il désirait.
> <sub>—L’Équilibre européen à la fin du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Français et Russes vis-à-vis la triple alliance. / Paul Marin, 1890</sub>
>
> Notre route le suit et, de temps à autre, pour en traverser les affluents desséchés, la diligence descend et remonte des pentes mouvantes, avec une rapidité qui donne la sensation fugitive mais poignante que l’on s’en va chercher ***dans les montagnes russes***.
> <sub>—Autour de la Méditerranée.... de Tunis à Alger / Marius Bernard, 1902</sub>
>
> [...] une photographie du canot d’Arcachon récemment inauguré, au moment où il abandonne son chariot sur rails perchés en l’air comme ***dans les montagnes russes*** pour prendre possession de son élément.
> <sub>—Touche-à-tout : revue hebdomadaire universelle illustrée, 1904</sub>
>
> Comme ***dans les montagnes russes***, on remonte tout à coup brusquement pour redescendre plus vite encore. On traverse des ravins profonds, des barrancas, dans la langue du pays, dont le fond est semé de grosses pierres, et même de bancs de rochers.
> <sub>—Le Mexique et ses mines d’argent / Albert Bordeau, 1910</sub>
>
> [...] dois faire deux fois le tour du bassin et des jets d’eau, errer ***dans les montagnes russes*** du passage surélevé avant de me faufiler jusqu’aux rues du Madrid autrichien [...]
> <sub>—Et la ville ta douceur / Jean-François Dionnot, 1973</sub>
>
> C’était ***comme dans les montagnes russes***, ***comme sur la grande roue***, un mélange de cris de joie et de frayeur, de gémissements et de vertiges [...] → *Note : un intéressant contraste ici entre les montagnes russes (dans) et la grande roue (sur).*
> <sub>—Le fils de l’Himalaya / Jacques Lanzmann, 1997</sub>
>
> Emmanuel était mécontent : son portefeuille avait glissé de sa poche **dans les montagnes russes**, ce qui allait le priver de marijuana durant la semaine.
> <sub>—Le petit dernier / Philippe Colin-Olivier, 2000 (Paris)</sub>
>
> Au premier rang des grands projets que je m’étais promis de réaliser avant l’âge de vingt ans, il y avait, juste derrière la découverte de la mer, une visite aux momies égyptiennes du Louvre et un tour ***dans les montagnes russes*** de la foire du Trône qu’un camarade de classe m’avait un jour décrites de manière enthousiaste [...]
> <sub>—La bande de Fort Apache / Jacques Asklund, 2000</sub>
>
> Ce premier opus nous envoie parfois ***dans des montagnes russes émotionnelles***, collant à la personnalité dynamique et explosive de la demoiselle.
> <sub>—Description de l’album *Lush* de Snail Mail, 2018</sub>

Le *« tour »* peut donc s’effectuer **sur** les montagnes russes ou **dans** les montagnes russes. L’usage varie dans la population, mais il se pourrait bien qu’il soit assez stable pour les individus particuliers.

En effet, si l’on cherchait ce qu’apporte au discours l’une ou l’autre préposition, on pourrait proposer que **sur** indique une domination de la personne sur l’élément, comme le cavalier domine sa monture ou le surfer domine la vague qu’il chevauche, et que **dans**, au contraire, indique un absorption de la personne par l’élément, comme on peut se trouver *dans* un tunnel, ou figurativement *dans* une période difficile. Mais j’ai tendance à croire qu’il s’agit là d’une suranalyse.

Dans les exemples proposés ci-dessus, nous avons bien *« errer dans les montagnes russes »*, où l’impuissance de l’errance est sans doute mieux transmise par ***dans*** qu’elle ne le serait par ***sur***, mais nous trouvons aussi un *« un chariot perché en l’air comme dans les montagnes russes »*, où ***sur*** eût selon moi mieux convenu à la situation perchée, ainsi que « sur les montagnes russes de l’air », pour lequel l’air me semble être un médium assez enveloppant pour justifier pleinement d’utiliser ***dans*** plutôt que ***sur***.

Le choix me semble donc justifié davantage par l’habitude personnelle que par le besoin de nuance précise.

---

#### Avant le tour de montagnes russes

Si l’on discute du fait de se rendre au manège, on rencontrera aussi régulièrement, en plus des précédents, ***aux** montagnes russes*, peut-être pour indiquer qu’avant d’y faire un tour, on doit rejoindre leur sphère d’influence, leur rayon d’action, qui se traduit par les gigantesques structures, la foule, les cris de ceux qui dévalent les pentes, le vacarme du train sur les rails, l’attente de son tour, etc. C’est en marge de la question, mais ça permet d’élargir le paysage.

> Et comme ***aux Montagnes Russes***, où ils étaient descendus, la comtesse s’était prise un instant de passion pour une nouvelle étoffe, qu’on lui étalait [...]
> <sub>—Les russes à Paris. Tome 1 / Paul de Julvécourt, 1843</sub>
>
> Je suis si étourdi que je ne songeai plus que Marika, la véritable femme fellah et le colosse de Rosette se devaient rendre ***aux montagnes russes*** de fort bonne heure.
> <sub>—La Vie parisienne : mœurs élégantes, choses du jour, fantaisies, voyages, théâtres, musique, modes / par Marcellin, 1916</sub>

Un exemple isolé, mais néanmoins élégant (une opinion qui n’engage ici que moi) :

> Hommes, femmes et enfants se dispersent à toutes jambes, en poussant des cris où l’épouvante se mêle au plaisir d’avoir peur... des cris tout pareils à ceux des midinettes de Paris « ***quand elles se paient les montagnes russes*** ».
> <sub>—La ville au bois dormant : de Saïgon à Ang-Kor en automobile... / Duc de Montpensier, 1910</sub>

---

#### Les montagnes russes métaphoriques

Diverses introductions des montagnes russes, avec ***en*** qui pourrait rappeler ***dans***, mais aussi selon des modalités qui sembleraient étranges utilisées dans le contexte original du manège, preuve que l’image s’est un peu émancipée de sa source.

> Le chemin se profile ***en montagnes russes*** ; montées et descentes se succèdent sans interruption, tantôt sur une rive, tantôt sur l’autre [...]
> <sub>—Bulletin pyrénéen / Club alpin français, 1905</sub>
>
> ***Par les montagnes russes*** de la route accidentée qui va de Rambervillers au pays de « charme les cœurs », nous revenons vers la vallée de la Moselle.
> <sub>—Pages de guerre écrites au jour le jour / (publié à Nancy), 1914</sub>
>
> On ne peut pas avoir confiance en valeurs qui voyagent ***en montagnes russes***. Seul, le professionnel peut y avoir par moment avantage, vu les conditions spéciales de courtage qui lui sont faites.
> <sub>—France-Europe orientale : bulletin officiel du Comité national d’expansion économique dans l’Europe orientale, 1924</sub>
>
> ***À travers ces montagnes russes*** de la vie actuelle, la ruée des aventuriers de tous les pays, et les intellectuels dévoyés par les hommes et femmes d’affaires, par ceux qui gagnent des millions en remuant du vent et faisant de la poussière.
> <sub>—Tuer les vieux, jouir ! : roman vache : moeurs du temps / par Félicien Champsaur, 1925</sub>
>
> Enfin, après une demi-heure ***de montagnes russes*** et de chocs brusques, impitoyables pour les organes de la voiture, nous nous retrouvons, indemnes, sur un sol ferme.
> <sub>—Bulletin de la Société de géographie de Lille, 1937</sub>
>
> Un étroit sentier ***en montagnes russes*** nous réserve jusqu’au bout quelques passages acrobatiques. Chaque clairière nous est une occasion d’arrêt et de nous regrouper pour une muette contemplation.
> <sub>—La Montagne : revue mensuelle du Club alpin français, 1939</sub>
>
> Sur les collines où s’agrippent les maisons de la ville naissante, desservies par des rues, des routes et des chemins qui ***jouent les montagnes russes***, on distingue déjà, à côté de bâtisses modestes, de riches habitations de style victorien, construites par les nouveaux enrichis, avec perron, colonnades [...]
> <sub>—Les voiles de la misère / Paul Malet, 2000 (Le Coudray-Macouard)</sub>

---

#### Au-delà des montagnes russes : concurrence entre SUR et DANS

Un curieux [nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dans+une+chaise%2Csur+une+chaise%2Cdans+un+fauteuil%2Csur+un+fauteuil%2Cdans+un+sofa%2Csur+un+sofa&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdans%20une%20chaise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20une%20chaise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20un%20fauteuil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20un%20fauteuil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20un%20sofa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20un%20sofa%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdans%20une%20chaise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20une%20chaise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20un%20fauteuil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20un%20fauteuil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20un%20sofa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csur%20un%20sofa%3B%2Cc0), qui propose que les deux prépositions pourraient n’en pas être à leur première prise de bec.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Le plus commun serait l'utilisation du "de" dans : "faire un tour de montagnes russes" . Le "en" serait, à mon avis, plus utilisé pour de longs déplacements comme en voiture, mais pas pour du divertissement de courte durée. L'utilisation de la préposition "sur" n'est pas une option, mais "dans" peut l'être. Voilà!

Comment: Répondre à une telle question sans s'appuyer sur des données, c'est pas très intéressant. Si tu veux un deuxième avis, en France « sur les » est ce qui me parait le plus habituel, bien que « de » fonctionne aussi (mon opinion ne faisant bien sûr pas autorité).